# What is the alternative to using bind when setting context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

i have been using the following syntax in my web app so far.

```
function.bind( obj );
```

So given i have an object like:

```
myObj = {
    msg: 'You have logged ',
    init: function(){
        $( 'input' ).on( 'click', this.log.bind( this ) ),
    },
    log: function( e ){
        console.log( this.msg + $( e.target ).val() );
    }
}
```

I can call the `init` function.
    myObj.init();

But the problem is i read that the .bind function() will be deprecated. Is that the jQuery bind function or the JavaScript bind function that is going to be deprecated.

If that is going to be the JavaScript function that is going to be deprecated then what is its alternative ?

Comment: Google it... It should be there

Comment: Per the jQuery docs, it's jQuery's being deprecated.

Comment: The JS `.bind()` function isn't ever going to be deprecated

Comment: @AndrewL. I hadn't heard - with any luck they'll deprecate the binding versions of `.click` et al too.  On my last project I made sure only ever to use `.on` and `.off`

Comment: @AndrewL. you sound like a JS guru. Wow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the problem is i read that the .bind function() will be deprecated. Is that the jQuery bind function or the JavaScript bind function that is going to be deprecated.

There is no problem because you're not using `$.bind`, you're using `Function.prototype.bind`

> If that is going to be the JavaScript function that is going to be deprecated then what is its alternative ?

`Function.prototype.bind` is not being deprecated. Your code is *mostly* fine, less the exceptions below

---

Some things to note about your code

```
// no `var`, `let` or `const` keyword
myObj = {
  msg: 'You have logged ',
  init: function(){
    // event handlers usually pass an `event` object
    $( 'input' ).on( 'click', this.log.bind( this ) ),
  },
  log: function(){ // no `e` param here
    console.log( this.msg + $( e.target ).val() );
  }
}
```

Could be updated to

```
var myObj = {
  msg: 'You have logged ',
  init: function(){
    $( 'input' ).on( 'click', this.log.bind( this ) ),
  },
  log: function(e){
    console.log( this.msg + $( e.target ).val() );
  }
}
```

---

And a completely alternative way to express the code using ES6 – [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) have a lexical `this` so no `Function.prototype.bind` is required in this example

```
const myObj = {
  msg: 'You have logged ',
  init () {
    $('input').on('click', event => this.log(event));
  }
  log (event) {
    console.log(this.msg, $(event.target).val());
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks @naomik Yes I had a confusion between jQuery's and Javascript's bind function. That's cleared now.

Comment: Great answer and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can currently use [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy). Though note `$.proxy()` may also be deprecated in future versions of jQuery.

```
$( 'input' ).on( 'click', $.proxy( this.log, this ) )
```

Comment: Note also, missing `e` parameter at `log` function, if you are expecting `input` to be `e.target`